# Explode on unescaped white space only in PHP

Tags: php, escaping, whitespace, explode

I would like to explode this kind of string in PHP:

```
$foo = "foo.txt da\ code.txt bar.txt";
```

And I want to explode it to have:

```
["foo.txt", "da\ code.txt", "bar.txt"]
```

I know I can use preg_split but I don't see what to put as regular expression.

Could someone help me?

Comment: It's not really "escaping" the space character... how did your data get in this strange format to begin with?

Comment: How do you differntiate between the first white space `foo.txt da` and the second white space `da\ code`. What are the rules?

Comment: Looks like you could `explode('.txt', $foo)`, `trim`, and put the `.txt` back on each array item. ???

Comment: @njk I just wasted 10min of my life and solved this totally for free hoping to get back some stackoverflow reputation witch is some abstract number that represents nothing. who's laughing now?

Comment: @fsw If you wasted it then didn't really help anyone did it?

Comment: In fact it's a common list of files in command line under GNU/Linux. If you have spaces in your files names you have to escape the space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could match on a positive look behind for any space preceded by alpha characters.

```
<?php
$foo = "foo.txt da\ code.txt bar.txt";

print_r(preg_split("/(?<=[a-zA-Z])\s/", $foo));
```

You could also use a negative lookbehind for the general case

```
<?php
$foo = "foo.txt da\ code.txt bar.txt something.mp3 other@ 9asdf";

print_r(preg_split('/(?<!\\\\)\s/', $foo));
```

Comment: The character classes specified in the look behind can easily be changed to suit the use case as needed.  http://codepad.org/vfopYmrm

Comment: Yes but you will have to expand it with all special chars a filename could end with so maybe better would be to look behind for not "\" like in my answer

Comment: Oops.  Just saw you added that to your answer.  I would agree this is definitely the preferred solution.

Comment: I like this method (I can use regex because I only have this do be done once). And I work with specific files `.rec` and not something other for my lib.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a funky, non-regex "parser". All *kinds* of fun. What was the world like before *regular expressions*? I mean, it must have been *work*. `;)`

```
<?php

$foo = "foo.txt da\ code.txt bar.txt";
$foos = array();
$char = 0;
$index = 0;
$lookback = '';

while ($char < strlen($foo)) {
    $lookback = $foo{$char-4} . $foo{$char-3} . $foo{$char-2} . $foo{$char-1} . $foo{$char};

    if ($lookback == '.txt ') $index++;

    $foos[$index] .= $foo{$char++};
}

print_r(array_map('trim', $foos));

?>
```

http://codepad.org/XMfLemeg

Comment: I don't want to use regex. I just want to have the simplest method. I already thought about this kind of solution (using string replacement for `\ ` like `__ESCAPED_SPACE__` and then explode with space.

Comment: Sure, that makes sense, if a little awkward. Also `$foos = explode('|', str_replace('.txt ', '.txt|', $foo));`, if `.txt` is consistent. Note the way I use `array_map` too.

Comment: I like this idea too. `.txt` is consistent for me (in real it is `.rec` files. This solution is far more clean than my "solution".

Answer (score 1):

You could use preg_split() but it is slow so if escaped space is your only problem a lot faster would be to do it as simply as:

```
$array1 = explode(' ', $list);
$array2 = [];
$appendNext = false;
foreach($array1 as $elem)
{
    if ($appendNext)
    {
        array_push($array2, array_pop($array2) . ' ' . $elem);
    }
    else
    {
        $array2[] = $elem;
    }
    $appendNext = (substr($elem, -1) === '\\');
}
var_dump($array2);
```

If you really want to do it via regex here is a working solution:

```
print_r(preg_split("/(?<!\\\)\s/", $foo));
```

http://codepad.org/ngbDaxA3
but it will be slower than above